# Install SSL certificate on the linux VM with .Net Core web API

Tags: linux, ssl, asp.net-core, certificate, virtual-machine

I have a Ubuntu VM on Azure with .Net Core 3 Web API application. I use a custom domain and got an SSL certificate file issued by the trusted CA. How can I set it up? Should it be a part of Linux or .Net Core configuration?

Surfing the web pointed me to the tutorial which suggests copying the certificate file to the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and run `sudo update-ca-certificates`. This does not work. The browser still complains.

This [.Net Core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) talks only about development certificates.

Comment: As Kestrel runs behind Apache or nginx, you should refer to their documentation on how to install certificates.

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you have just a VM with .netCore, the settings should be configured in the .NetCore application, not in the OS.

I was able to configure mine .netCore app to work with my certificate.
I found all the details in this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1